# braintree.paypalCheckout.create add dynamical amount to the paypal button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, paypal-rest-sdk, braintree-sandbox

I use HostedFields for credit card and paypal web for paypal.
So inside of `braintree.client.create` i have `braintree.hostedFields.create` and `braintree.paypalCheckout.create`.
Code example of paypal:

```
braintree.paypalCheckout.create({
            client: clientInstance
          }, function (paypalCheckoutErr, paypalCheckoutInstance) {

            if (paypalCheckoutErr) {
              console.error('Error creating PayPal Checkout:', paypalCheckoutErr);
              return;
            }

            paypal.Button.render({
              env: 'sandbox', 
              commit: true,
              buttonStyle: {
                  color: 'blue',
                  shape: 'rect',
                  size: 'medium'
                },      
              payment: function () {
                return paypalCheckoutInstance.createPayment({
                    flow: 'checkout', 
                    locale: ''+langanalytics+'',
                    amount: '10.00', 
                    currency: 'EUR'
                });
              },

              onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
                return paypalCheckoutInstance.tokenizePayment(data, function (err, payload) {
                    document.getElementById("paynonce").value = payload.nonce;
                    document.getElementById("paymentform").submit();
                });
              },

              onCancel: function (data) {
                console.log('checkout.js payment cancelled', JSON.stringify(data, 0, 2));
              },

              onError: function (err) {
                console.error('checkout.js error', err);
              }
            }, '#paypal-button').then(function () {

            });

          });
```

The problem is according to my client he want a single page checkout, where the amount get generated dynamically.
For example if someone change the country or payment method the price can change for some €. A click EventListener start the calculation and changes the total sum in real time.

**My Problem:**
I cant change the amount of my paypal intialization of this part:

```
return paypalCheckoutInstance.createPayment({
flow: 'checkout', 
locale: ''+langanalytics+'',
amount: '10.00', 
currency: 'EUR'
});
```

Is there any way to update the amount outsite of the function as soon as total sum changes (i have full control of this).
I already tried to intialize the whole `braintree.client.create` new on total sum change but i get errors from hosted fields a instance is already created and for paypal i recieve multiple buttons.